# Advanced Custom Fields plugin not showing image

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the [Advanced Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin and I want to insert an image into my page. I did all the settings back-end and also inserted short-code in the post page, but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<img src="the_field('image');">";
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I cleaned up the language for you a bit and formatted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you returning the image path or image object?

Assuming your option names are correct try and you are returning the image path:

```
echo '<img src="' . the_field('image') . '">';
```

Comment: Problem solved by using this `echo '<img src="' . get_field('image') . '">';`